# "Minimal Image" of Raspberry Pi SD Card

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, sd-card, diskimage

I have a small IOT app that I've developed on a Raspberry Pi. I'd like to try running the app of a few other Pi's around my apartment. I can make a disk image of the sd card with `dd`, but, the original disk is 32gb and mostly empty. Is there a way to make a disk image of just the contents of a drive/sd card? This way i can make copies to smaller (cheaper) sd cards. The original SD card was set up with NOOB.

Ordinarily, I'd deploy with something like ansible, but installing all the libraries used took over 8 hours!

Comment: I think you can make a smaller partition on the disk and clone only the partition with dd, without cloning all the disk.

Comment: how do i do that?

Comment: dd if=/disk/partition of=file.img

Comment: right, perhaps I wasn't clear. I understand how to make an image. How do I make a partition, the right partition, smaller?

Comment: Just use a partitioning tool, you can download it and install on a USB stick than just boot the USB stick and make it. Try to use GPart.